# creating & destroying views in Emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I have an application that lists clients and allow the user to create a new client in a modal dialog. I create and append the client view to the Dom only when i handle the new Client button click.

I'm not sure how views get destroyed or at what frequency is that done, so before i I create the clientView i keep a copy of it and next time the user intends to create a new client, i serve the same view.

Is it the right approach or I rather destroy the view when the user saves or cancels the operation, and keep creating a new view each time it's needed.

I looked at the source code for connectOutlet and apparently a new view is created each time a call to connectOutlet is made.

Can anyone validate this ?

Comment: you have a list of clients say in a sidebar, you click the plus button which pops a modal dialog with a form may be to add a new client, once the client is saved the list of clients should get updated with the new client right ? can you please explain what's it with creating and destroying the client view ?

Comment: The client view is appended to the DOM only when it's needed and destroyed when no longer is useful.

Comment: so want the view to be present even when the modal page is visible, right ?

Comment: The view is displayed in a modal once the user click on a button "show modal". So yes it has to be created at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that connectOutlet creates a new view each time it runs. Typically, view creation is cheap enough to do as needed. So you don't need to worry about keeping the view around.

Comment: That's what i thought following connectOutlet example. However, since i was doing some Dom manipulation after the element insertion, my selector was returning multiple instances of the element. I had to store an instance of the view, as mentioned above, to overcome the issue. Now are you suggesting that i can do without the stored instance and just keep destroying it when i'm done using the view ?

Comment: @ken, I don't think I understand your use case. Normally, you can deal with extra DOM manipulation by performing it within `didInsertElement`, using `this.$()` as your scoped jQuery object, and doing any necessary cleanup in `willDestroyElement`.